# How can solve this error, internal node_modules not found,i'm getting tired to fix this

Tags: npm

My create-react-app not working when I run the following command:

```
npm install create-react-app -g
```

Here is the output I get:

```
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Raisa IT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\Raisa IT\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app.cmd
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\Raisa IT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js' -> 'C:\Users\Raisa IT\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app.cmd'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\Raisa IT\AppData\Roaming\npm\create-react-app.cmd
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Raisa IT\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-06T13_18_41_018Z-debug.log
```

How would I go about solving this issue?

Comment: I would suggest to use `npx create-react-app my-app` as mentioned in [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)

Answer (score 0):

This error is saying that `create-react-app` already exists. Try running `create-react-app`.

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Raisa IT\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\index.js'.they show me module can not find